# Jquery "rermoveClass" doesn't work with popup in (done with elementor wordpress)

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my code:

```
jQuery('#scheda').click(
       function(open){jQuery('.bginfo, .bginfo6, .bg5').addClass('shown') },
     );
```

to make some elements visible by adding a class with opacity: 1, at the click of a section on a page. It works correctly, but if I apply the reverse logic to the click of an image within a pop up this code does not work.

```
jQuery('#closex').click(
       function(){jQuery('.bginfo6, .bginfo').css('opacity','0') },
     );
```

I don't understand why. can you help me?
here the page link: http://tuscany.designce.it/classic-florence-and-beyond/

You can try the error by clicking on the second image with the title hover "essential florence", you will see that elements appear on the map that should disappear when the pop up closes, more precisely when the "X" is clicked.

thank you

Comment: Most likely your "closex" doesn't exist at the time your code runs, so you'll need event delegation, try:  `$(document).on("click", "#closex", function...`

Comment: If you just want to reverse and hide the elements which was shown by `addClass()`, why not do `jQuery('.bginfo, .bginfo6, .bg5').removeClass('shown')` instead of setting opacity directly.

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for your reply @freedomn-m i tried to modify as you indicated but it still doesn't work. here is my code:  `jQuery('#pop').on('click', 'a', function(){
    jQuery('.bginfo6, .bginfo').removeClass('shown') },);`.   `#pop` is the id of the popup, so I should have delegated the event to its loading correct?